# PyAudio failed to install on Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, pyaudio

When I am trying to install PyAudio using

```
pip install pyaudio
```

I get this error:

```
C:\Users\pankajkaun>pip install pyaudio
Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/42/b4f04721c5c5bfc196ce156b3c768998ef8c0ae3654ed29ea5020c749a6b/PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
  Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\pankajkaun\desktop\python\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\PANKAJ~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-pw8_ueh5\\pyaudio
\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\PANKAJ~1\AppData\Local\Temp
\pip-record-eru_9orv\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMS_WIN64=1 -Ic:\users\pankajkaun\desktop\python\include -Ic:\users\pankajkaun\desktop\python\
include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt" "-
IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt" "-IC:
\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
    _portaudiomodule.c
    c:\users\pankajkaun\desktop\python\include\pyconfig.h(117): warning C4005: 'MS_WIN64': macro redefinition
    src/_portaudiomodule.c: note: see previous definition of 'MS_WIN64'
    src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'portaudio.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\pankajkaun\desktop\python\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\PANKAJ~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-pw8_ueh5\\pyaudio
\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record 
C:\Users\PANKAJ~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-eru_9orv\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\PANKAJ~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pw8_ueh5\pyaudio\
```

Any idea what's going on in here?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Try this (in admin mode command prompt):

```
pip install pipwin
pipwin install pyaudio
```

pipwin is like pip, but it installs precompiled Windows binaries provided by Christoph Gohlke. Saves you a lot of googling and manual downloading.

Comment: except that 'pipwin' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Comment: raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

Comment: if pipwin isn't added as a command you can use:
`python -m pipwin  install pyaudio`

Answer (score 12):

According to [official docs of pyaudio](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/):

> **Microsoft Windows**
>
> Install using pip:
>
> *python -m pip install pyaudio*
>
> Notes: pip will fetch and install PyAudio wheels (prepackaged binaries). Currently, there are wheels compatible with the official distributions of Python 2.7, **3.4, 3.5, and 3.6**. For those versions, both 32-bit and 64-bit wheels are available.

You try to install pyaudio for 3.7, so it try to compile it.
Download and install wheel from [Gohlke - Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/). Wheels for 32 and 64-bit python 3.7 are available.

Comment: So you did installed it as I suggested, using whl from Gohlke?

Comment: So is it recommended to use pipwin for mostly all pip installs?

Answer (score 5):

Use this link to download the .whl file according to the python version it supports:
**[https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio)**

Then, go to the following directory and run this command on the command prompt:

```
C:\Users\shris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts> pip install PyAudio-0.2.11-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl
```

Answer (score 3):

Run CMD as admin then run the following two commands:

1. **pip install pipwin**
2. **pipwin install pyaudio**

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I solved it by using the WHL file which you can download from:
[https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio).

There are several versions that you can download and use.
For example, PyAudio-0.2.11-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl.

For installing purposes on the command prompt, write

```
pip install "path"\PyAudio-0.2.11-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to install portaudio first.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my computer configuration:

- Windows 10
- Python 3.8.0 installed on `C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Python38-32`

I've got the same issue and i solved it with these steps:

1. download *PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp38‑cp38‑win32.whl* from [**here**](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio) on my computer in `C:\Downloads\PyAudio-0.2.11-cp38-cp38-win32.whl`
2. run `C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Python38-32\Scripts>pip3.8 install C:\Downloads\PyAudio-0.2.11-cp38-cp38-win32.whl --user`