# pip is showing error while installing pyaudio

Tags: python, pip, pyaudio

I am trying to install pyAudio with pip, I have also try pyaudio, I don't know why this is happening , it is showing some error , please some one tell me solution

```
pip install pyAudio
```

This is the error

```
Collecting pyAudio
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/42/b4f04721c5c5bfc196ce156b3c768998ef8c0ae3654ed29ea5020c749a6
b/PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: pyAudio
  Running setup.py install for pyAudio ... error
    ERROR: Complete output from command 'c:\users\sagar sisodiya\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' -
u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\SAGARS~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-lcx2zzgz\\pyAudio
\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');
f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\SAGARS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-reco
rd-_tc_wql7\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    ERROR: running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.m
icrosoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "'c:\users\sagar sisodiya\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools,
 tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\SAGARS~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-lcx2zzgz\\pyAudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getatt
r(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(c
ode, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\SAGARS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-_tc_wql7\install-reco
rd.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\SAGARS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\
pip-install-lcx2zzgz\pyAudio\
```

Comment: https://github.com/benfred/implicit/issues/76#issuecomment-360872999

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pyAudio failed to install : Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53866104/pyaudio-failed-to-install-windows-10)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+install+%5Bpyaudio%5D

Answer (score 1):

You should install C++ redistributables, it is emphasized in the traceback output:

> error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

I believe this is a shortcut link to the installation package: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install pipwin
```

```
pipwin install pyaudio
```

Try these commands in prompt this will definitely work. It does not require any manual downloads or searches etc. It will automatically search for the compatible wheel for your python version and will install it. pipwin is a complementary tool for pip on Windows. pipwin installs unofficial python package binaries for windows provided by Christoph Gohlke

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `visual studio` from this link [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=Community&rel=16)

**OR**

You can download `PyAudio` package from this link [Window Binary for python](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)
. In this website go to the `PyAudio` package and then download it, Now go to the location where this file is downloaded on your laptop with window PowerShell, AND then run `pip install <filename>`.

It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to download or any Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools. Just do the following, it will fix everything. I had the exact same error.
After you go to this link: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ select and download the PyAudio for your Python version.

I downloaded:

`PyAudio-0.2.11-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl`

Place the downloaded file into the Scrips folder. My folder structure is:

```
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\Scripts`
```

Then you need to install the downloaded script by using the command:

`python -m pip install "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\Scripts\PyAudio-0.2.11-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl"`

Answer (score 0):

For those users who are using `Python 3.9` should carry out this procedure, it might help you as it worked fine for me.

```
pip install pipwin
pipwin install pyaudio
```