# Missing files with PyAudio installed with PIP?

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install PyAudio for a project. I have added the path of my python installation `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64` and the Scripts subfolder. I am running an elevated CMD instance. I type: `pip install PyAudio`. The build process begins. below is the output:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.592]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install PyAudio
Collecting PyAudio
  Using cached PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz (37 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: PyAudio
  Building wheel for PyAudio (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\aweso\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-mi36cn5j\\PyAudio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\aweso\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-mi36cn5j\\PyAudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\aweso\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-7out287e'
       cwd: C:\Users\aweso\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mi36cn5j\PyAudio\
  Complete output (17 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
  copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
  running build_ext
  building '_portaudio' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMS_WIN64=1 "-Ic:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\include" "-Ic:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
  _portaudiomodule.c
  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\include\pyconfig.h(117): warning C4005: 'MS_WIN64': macro redefinition
  src/_portaudiomodule.c: note: see previous definition of 'MS_WIN64'
  src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'portaudio.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.24.28314\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for PyAudio
  Running setup.py clean for PyAudio
Failed to build PyAudio
Installing collected packages: PyAudio
    Running setup.py install for PyAudio ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\aweso\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-mi36cn5j\\PyAudio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\aweso\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-mi36cn5j\\PyAudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\aweso\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-e30_qx6x\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\Include\PyAudio'
         cwd: C:\Users\aweso\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mi36cn5j\PyAudio\
    Complete output (17 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMS_WIN64=1 "-Ic:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\include" "-Ic:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
    _portaudiomodule.c
    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\include\pyconfig.h(117): warning C4005: 'MS_WIN64': macro redefinition
    src/_portaudiomodule.c: note: see previous definition of 'MS_WIN64'
    src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'portaudio.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.24.28314\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\aweso\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-mi36cn5j\\PyAudio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\aweso\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-mi36cn5j\\PyAudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\aweso\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-e30_qx6x\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\Include\PyAudio' Check the logs for full command output.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

From what I understand, the wheel cannot be built because `_portaudiomodule.c` is trying to include `portaudio.h`, which doesn't exist for some reason.

After failing to build the wheel, pip then tries to run `setup.py`, which again calls `portaudiomodule.c`, which again cannot include `portaudio.h`.

Is this an error with the package on pypi.org or with my installation of pip?

Python 3.7.5, installed under Visual Studio Community 2019.
Windows 10 Home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there's an issue with the version in PyPi. (See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53866104/pyaudio-failed-to-install-windows-10#answer-53866322))

The maintainers of PyAudio haven't built it for python 3.7 running on Windows, so your system is trying to compile it, and fails.

If you have access to Python 3.6 you should be able to install from PyPi on there.

It looks like the best way to get it working on Python 3.7 is to use the pre-built wheels from [Christoph Gohlke](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio)

Edit: updating with installation instructions ([reference](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#installing-from-wheels))

You'll want the wheel specific to your version and build of python (3.7, 64-bit) so you'll want to download `PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl`

Then provide that file to pip e.g.

```
pip install C:\Users\AwsesomeCronk\Downloads\PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl
```

If Visual Studio is doing anything funny with your environment, like hiding system files, you may need to copy the .whl file over into your project directory and install from there.

Comment: How do I implement those wheels?