# When I try to download PyAudio I just got this error message. This is so painful. Pls pleh

Tags: python, cmd, pip, download, pyaudio

C:\Users\lansz>pip install pyaudio

```
  Using cached PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz (37 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: pyaudio
  Building wheel for pyaudio (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\lansz\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\lansz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ttc_7ppq\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\lansz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ttc_7ppq\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\lansz\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-661td9fy'
       cwd: C:\Users\lansz\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ttc_7ppq\pyaudio\
  Complete output (17 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  running build_ext
  building '_portaudio' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMS_WIN64=1 -Ic:\users\lansz\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -Ic:\users\lansz\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
  _portaudiomodule.c
  c:\users\lansz\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include\pyconfig.h(117): warning C4005: 'MS_WIN64': macro redefinition
  src/_portaudiomodule.c: note: see previous definition of 'MS_WIN64'
  src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'portaudio.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyaudio
  Running setup.py clean for pyaudio
Failed to build pyaudio
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
    Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\lansz\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\lansz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ttc_7ppq\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\lansz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ttc_7ppq\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\lansz\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-gaglivtc\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\lansz\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\pyaudio'
         cwd: C:\Users\lansz\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ttc_7ppq\pyaudio\
    Complete output (17 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMS_WIN64=1 -Ic:\users\lansz\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -Ic:\users\lansz\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
    _portaudiomodule.c
    c:\users\lansz\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include\pyconfig.h(117): warning C4005: 'MS_WIN64': macro redefinition
    src/_portaudiomodule.c: note: see previous definition of 'MS_WIN64'
    src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'portaudio.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\lansz\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\lansz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ttc_7ppq\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\lansz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ttc_7ppq\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\lansz\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-gaglivtc\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\lansz\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\pyaudio' Check the logs for full command output.
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.3; however, version 21.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'c:\users\lansz\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

============================================================
:c
I'm watching btw Tech With Tim's tutorial, the "Coronavirus Webscraper" video.
I don’t know what to do with my life and I’ve been suffering with it for 5 hours.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+%5Bpyaudio%5D+fatal+error+C1083%3A+Cannot+open+include+file%3A+portaudio.h+No+such+file+or+directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help, since it is the same problem you are having:

[pyAudio failed to install : Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53866104/pyaudio-failed-to-install-windows-10/53866322)

Basically you are missing some components you need before download pyaudio, and those are included by pipwin before installing so you don't have to do it yourself.

Comment: Yeah, thank you so much. <3