# Install Unofficial Windows Binaries by more Unix way

Tags: python, windows, pip, chocolatey, scoop-installer

I am wondering if there is a more elegant way how to install Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages. Something like installing the python version by pip (or installing the python version by scoop or chocolatey)?

Thank you!

Comment: The whole reason why unofficial binaries for Windows exist is because "the Unix way", that is, compiling from source, is not always straightforward on Windows, especially for Python programmers who know little about the Microsoft C development ecosystem.

Comment: Okay, so what I understand - it is desired to download so-called wheels and install them "manually".

Comment: No, but Windows users have little alternative if module packagers don't have the resources to include Windows binaries in the modules they make available to PyPI.

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you!

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/pipwin/

Comment: @phd It seems promising! I think it can be the answer to my question! Thx

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56354995/7976758 This is quite a typical advice https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+pipwin