# pip can't build pyaudio wheel on Windows 64-bit

Tags: python, windows, pyaudio

I'm trying to do

```
pip install Pyaudio
```

but I get this error:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: pyaudio
  Building wheel for pyaudio (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [17 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
      copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
      running build_ext
      building '_portaudio' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMS_WIN64=1 -IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include -IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\cppwinrt /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
      _portaudiomodule.c
      C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\pyconfig.h(117): warning C4005: 'MS_WIN64': macro redefinition
      src/_portaudiomodule.c: note: see previous definition of 'MS_WIN64'
      src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'portaudio.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyaudio
  Running setup.py clean for pyaudio
Failed to build pyaudio
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
  Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for pyaudio did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [17 lines of output]
      running install
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
      copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
      running build_ext
      building '_portaudio' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMS_WIN64=1 -IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include -IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\cppwinrt /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
      _portaudiomodule.c
      C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\pyconfig.h(117): warning C4005: 'MS_WIN64': macro redefinition
      src/_portaudiomodule.c: note: see previous definition of 'MS_WIN64'
      src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'portaudio.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> pyaudio

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip
```

I have installed VS build tools.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pyAudio failed to install on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53866104/pyaudio-failed-to-install-on-windows-10)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the Python version you're using is not compatible with the pyAudio.

Please refer to the docs [here](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/#:%7E:text=pip%20will%20fetch%20and%20install%20PyAudio%20wheels%20(prepackaged%20binaries).%20Currently%2C%20there%20are%20wheels%20compatible%20with%20the%20official%20distributions%20of%20Python%202.7%2C%203.4%2C%203.5%2C%20and%203.6.%20For%20those%20versions%2C%20both%2032%2Dbit%20and%2064%2Dbit%20wheels%20are%20available.).